# Insert records from array in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have an array of 1500000 records in it as below

```
Array = ["2","3","6","7","A5057",......]
```

How would I be able to insert all this records in a table(which has only one field(XXX_id)) directly from the MySQL command I tried with the below query

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (XXX_id) VALUES (["2","3","6","7","A5057",......]);
```

If we have to insert from php script, no doubt we can follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604310/insert-into-table-from-array-php) form community.

Comment: you will need a procedure for what you want to to

Comment: use the stored procedure,first split the array into rows and store them into temporary table .Then after insert  data from temporary table to physical table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two ways you can do this

```
1.LOAD INFILE

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  
'path/file.csv'
INTO TABLE giata_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

2.Use [multi-row insert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE_NAME`(`XXX_id`) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create array format like this

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE_NAME`(`XXX_id`) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)
```

[Read more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [multi-row insert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) to achieve what you want

Just format your array as `VALUES (X), (X), ...` with PHP

Comment: I think trying to do that for 1.5 million rows will exceed the max_packet_size limit.

Comment: This is MySQL server dependant from the Op (and changeable anyway) but it's still the optimized way for very large insert

Answer (score 1):

Put the array data into a file, with one ID per line. Then you can use `LOAD DATA INFILE`:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename'
INTO TABLE table_name (XXX_id)
```

Comment: I am trying to insert the records from phpmyadmin.

Comment: You tagged it `php`.

Comment: There are no arrays in phpMyAdmin. It's a web interface, not a programming language. So now your question makes no sense.

Comment: My mistake, I changed the tags.

Comment: Yes you are correct I can't use array but can change my array to the format as @Plotisateur mentioned.

Comment: I created a .csv file where it shows 140613 records but then when I load the values in a table in shows total records 140466.

Comment: Maybe there was a duplicate in the file. It should have reported an error when it got there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157539/discussion-between-mohammed-abrar-ahmed-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1):

Your Query should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (XXX_id) VALUES (2),(3),(6),(7),(A5057),......;
```

But you are going to insert larege amount of rows with just one Query. So, it may exceeds to MySQL query limitation. Every query is limited by max_allowed_packet in general for MySQL.

1) Execute the following command in in MySQL to view default value for 'max_allowed_packet ':

```
show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
```

2) Standard MySQL installation has a default value of 1048576 bytes (1MB). But this can be increased by setting the higher value to 500MB or may be more:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=524288000;
```

3) Check max_allowed_packet value again by following 1) command in MySQL.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

we can use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  
'path/file.csv'
INTO TABLE giata_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

This will fetch all the records in a table we have to make sure that the field name in the table and the heading in the csv file matches the same.

If this didn't works for you then you can follow the @Plotisateur and @Aiyaz khorajia answer as

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE_NAME`(`XXX_id`) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string =  ' (" '.implode(' "),(" ',$array).' ") ';
$query = "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (XXX_id) VALUES {$string}";

IF you have large number of records, I would suggest you to make a bunch of 100-200 records and then insert:

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($array); $i++){

   $string = $string==""?'('.$array[$i].')':$string.',('.$array[$i].')';
   if($i % 100 == 0){
     $query = INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (XXX_id) VALUES ($string);
     // execute the query
    $string = "";
  }
}

if($string != ""){
$query = INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (XXX_id) VALUES ($string);
     // execute the query
}
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to put them all into one record, I think each one is a separate row.

Answer (score 0):

do the following stuff in your procedure to get rid of your problems:

```
-- Temporary table to hold splited row value of string


drop temporary table if exists temp_convert;
        create temporary table temp_convert(split_data varchar(2056) );

       -- dynamic query to break comma separated string as rows and 

insert into column
        set @sql = concat("
        insert into temp_convert (split_data) 
                               values ('", replace(
        ( select group_concat(in_string) as converted_data), ",", "'),('"),"'
                                                   );"
        );
        prepare stmt1 from @sql;
        execute stmt1;
```